# (Eclipse - OS X) How do you copy from javadoc popups?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, javadoc

Coming from Windows, when I use Eclipse and mouse over a class / method / variable that has a Javadoc - a Javadoc window pops up (or alternatively you can hit F2). Eclipse on Mac OS X 10.8.2 has the same behavior. However where they differ is that in windows I can highlight content in the popup window and copy it (Ctrl+C) and then paste it somewhere. I cannot get this to work in Mac OS X 10.8.2. I've tried both command key + C (which works everywhere else) and I've also tried Ctrl+C. No dice.

I use this frequently when setting a local variable to a value returned by a getter method. I can just open the Javadoc and copy the return type, and then paste it into the editor as the type for my new local variable. It saves a lot of time if the return type is a complicated Map type with generic arguments.

Also it is helpful when helping out co-workers to be able to copy / paste portions of the Javadoc to them via IM.

Is this not possible on Mac OS X 10.8.2? Is there a work around?

**Edit**: Using Eclipse Juno SR 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you highlight the class/method/variable you are interested in, at the bottom of your Eclipse window there should be a list of tabs alongside console, one of which named Javadoc.

If you select this tab, the Javadoc should show in the window where your console normally appears, and you can copy using CMD-c as normal.

EDIT:
If Javadoc doesn't show, make sure to enable it from Window > Show View > Javadoc

Comment: Thank you. I wish they would fix this, but you definitely gave a solid work around. I'm so happy now!

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be a bug.  For me, it will only copy the first time.  Anytime after that you try to copy, it doesn't work -- until you restart Eclipse.  Also affects Javadoc view unfortunately, but not the editor.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback that I am not the only one with this problem. Although for me the javadoc view does allow me to copy paste - just not the popup dialog.